# Import data into sql developer from .csv file

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have to import some data in my Shipment table from .csv file,but i have problem with imorting DATE. 
Here is you can see my generator:

```
class Shipment extends Generator
{
    private String snd_time;
    private String dliv_time;
    private int deliv_id;
    private int post_id;
    int d, m, y, rnd;

    public Shipment() throws FileNotFoundException, Exception
    {
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter("ShipmentData.csv");
        for(int i = 1; i < 100001; i++){
            m = 1 + r.nextInt(12);
            y = 2005 + r.nextInt(16);
            if(m == 1 || m == 3 || m ==5 || m ==7 || m ==8 || m ==10 || m ==12)
                d = 1+r.nextInt(31);
            if(m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11)
                d = 1 + r.nextInt(30);
            if((y % 4 == 0) && m == 2)
                d = 1 + r.nextInt(29);
            if((y % 4 ) != 0 && m == 2 )
                d = 1 + r.nextInt(28);
            if(m >= 10 && d >= 10)
                snd_time = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);
            if(m < 10 && d < 10)
                snd_time = "0" + Integer.toString(d) + "/" + "0" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);
            if(d < 10 && m >= 10)
                snd_time = "0" +  Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" +Integer.toString(y);
            if(m < 10 && d >= 10)
                snd_time = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + "0" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);


            rnd = 1 + r.nextInt(7);
            if(m == 1 || m == 3 || m ==5 || m ==7 || m ==8 || m ==10 || m ==12)
            {
                if((d + rnd) > 31 ) {
                    d = (d + rnd) - 31;
                    m++;
                    if(m > 12) {
                        m = 1;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                if((d + rnd) < 31)
                    d += rnd;
            }
            if(m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11)
            {
                if((d + rnd) > 30) {
                    d = (d + rnd) - 30;
                    m++;
                    if(m > 12) {
                        m = 1;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                if((d + rnd) < 30)
                    d += rnd;
            }
            if((y % 4 == 0) && m == 2)
            {
                if((d + rnd) > 29) {
                    d = (d + rnd) - 29;
                    m++;
                    if(m > 12) {
                        m = 1;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                if((d + rnd) < 29)
                    d += rnd;
            }

            if((y % 4 ) != 0 && m == 2 )
            {
                if((d + rnd) > 28) {
                    d = (d + rnd) - 28;
                    m++;
                    if(m > 12) {
                        m = 1;
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                if((d + rnd) < 28)
                    d += rnd;
            }

            if(m >= 10 && d >= 10)
                dliv_time = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);
            if(m < 10 && d < 10)
                dliv_time = "0" + Integer.toString(d) + "/" /*+ "0"*/ + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);
            if(d < 10 && m >= 10)
                dliv_time = "0" +  Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" +Integer.toString(y);
            if(m < 10 && d >= 10)
                dliv_time = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + "0" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);

            deliv_id = 1 + r.nextInt(100000);
            post_id = 1 + r.nextInt(100000);
            wr.println(i + "," + this.snd_time + "," + this.dliv_time + "," + this.deliv_id + "," + this.post_id );
        }
        wr.close();
    }

}
```

Here is my ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'D:\databaseProject\Data\ShipmentData.csv'
INSERT INTO TABLE shipment
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
id,
send_time,
deliv_time DATE "dd/mm/yyyy",
delivery_id DATE "dd/mm/yyyy",
post_id 
)
```

but when i load this ctl file i get this error

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table SHIPMENT, column SEND_TIME.
ORA-01843: not a valid month

I've tried to write my date without 0, but it still doesn't work and i cannot find a solution for my problem

Comment: Problem is in data you're trying to load. Some strings have invalid value for MM. For example, 18 (as there isn't 18th month in our calendar).

Comment: Including sample data, particularly row 4, might be useful, along with the table definition. From the error `send_time` is a date or timestamp, but you haven't specified the format for that column in your control file, so it will rely on NLS settings. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Littlefoot but all months is correct